# Mac - Tool to slow down the network for Development testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

is there a Mac Tool that can simulate a internet connection for local development testing purposes?

I want to test ajax loaders etc, but since it's a local machine it's to fast?

Rails 3 App on a Mac, locally hosted

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The SpeedLimit prefpane by mschrag does what you want:

http://mschrag.github.com/

I'm not sure if it works for localhost, but it works great for everything else, and it's incredibly easy to use, so it's definitely worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that WaterRoof does what you're looking for. It acts as a frontend for ipfw, a packet filter for FreeBSD, which OS X is based on. NoobProof is a simpler interface for the same system, if you want to try that as well.

http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/

http://www.hanynet.com/noobproof/

Comment: More specifically, you want to use ipfw's [dummynet](http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) feature -- you can use it to feed packets through "pipes", where each pipe can have limited bandwidth, latency, and even packet loss.  See [this AFP548 article](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20060214081244545) for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.charlesproxy.com/ is the best I found for OS X.